# Насколько глубоко нужно использовать TypeScript в React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hook, typescript-типы

Изучила основы ts, понимаю, что кода мы создаём переменные мы используем типы данных, но вопрос нужно ли всегда указывать вот такие специфичные типы данных функций React.ChangeEvent или это лишние и достаточно, просто только указывать типы данных переменных? Также проблема, где можно найти все такие обозначения для функций React.

```
const [dinput, setDinput] = useState<string>('TS Input проверка') 

    const tsinput = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setDinput(event.target.value);

    }

       <input onChange={tsinput}
                placeholder="TS Input проверка"
            />
```

Comment: typescript довольно много может вывести сам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все зависит от настройки вашей среды разработки и файла `tsconfig`. Если TypeScript понимает что условный объект является объектом с правильными ключами, то не надо аннотировать его типы. В данном примере всегда нужно аннотировать чтобы TypeScript знал это синтетический event реакта и не вывел его как `any`.

### Книга Профессиональный TypeScript. Разработка масштабируемых JavaScript-приложений.

Стр 24.

Если вы хотите чтобы TypeScript вывел за вас типы, то просто не прописывайте их:

```
let a = 1                      // а является number
let b = 'hello'                // b является string
let c = [true, false]          // c является массивом booleans
```

Вы сразу убедитесь, насколько хорошо он справляется с этой задачей. Убрав аннотации, вы увидите, что типы остались прежними. На протяжении всей книги мы будем использовать аннотирование только по необходимости и позволим TypeScript демонстрировать свои волшебные способности.

*В большинстве случаев лучше позволить TypeScript выводить типы по мере его возможностей и снижать тем самым объем явно аннотированного кода до минимума.*